# Get title, album and artist from expo asset

Tags: react-native, expo, media, audio-player

I'm trying to create music player using expo and react native. now I can get the audios using expo media library and I get a detail that doesn't include title or album or artist. I was wondering how I can get this detail from assets uri or id.